# No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._dist_metrics'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric, NearestNeighbors
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world"

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    cgpa = request.form.get('cgpa')
    iq = request.form.get('iq')
    profile_score = request.form.get('profile_score')

    input_query = np.array([[cgpa,iq,profile_score]])

    result = model.predict(input_query)[0]

    return jsonify({'placement':str(result)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\student-placement-predictor-android-app\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._dist_metrics'
```

Comment: Line 4 import didn't throw an error, while line 5 load did. I would guess that your sklearn model stored in the pickle file has a different version from your current environment's sklearn version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.